# How can I prevent WifiManager.getConnectionInfo from triggering a location check?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

When my app has location permissions on Android and I want to get the IP of the phone, calling `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo` is triggering a location event on `AppOpsManager`. Since Google says my app is using the location in the background, I think this is one of the reasons why. My app needs the IP of the phone for communication with other devices and it starts getting that information on `Application.onCreate()`. I can probably move the code to get the ip to be called later (not `onCreate`), but it isn't a simple task, will probably involve a serious rewrite.

I do have other ways of getting the IP but given the variety of devices out there, this is one of the more reliable ways.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Edit: This issue just became a bigger problem for me because a third party library I require apparently makes a called to `WifiManager` after the app goes on the background as well.

Comment: `WifiInfo` has SSIDs, MAC addresses, and stuff, which can be used in some cases to identify the device's general location. That's why you need location permissions on newer versions of Android.

Comment: But checking the SSID for location (which I don't), shouldn't be viewed as using background location on devices with API < 29 if the real reason for blocking that is battery usage. I just wish Google would make these things clear so I don't end up wasting a week analyzing a third party library I have little control of, since that is the last place I'm seeing a call to `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo` on the background happening.

Comment: "But checking the SSID for location (which I don't)" -- `WifiInfo` has that data, whether you happen to be using it or not. I certainly can see arguments for Google offering finer-grained APIs, so you can get non-privacy-related data separately. However, in NAT-less environments, the device's IP address itself might have ties to location. And, years ago, at least some mobile carriers handed out public IP addresses to devices (Vodafone comes to mind). I do not know if that is current practice.

Comment: Please don't give them ideas, if they block me from getting the LAN ip completely then my app will become almost useless :(

Comment: Oh, that's right, this is WiFi. Ignore the Vodafone reference -- I was thinking about IP addresses more generally. Sorry for that mistake!